# AnjularJS Controller not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use one controller to generate two objects for a table.  The controller looks like this:

```
function LineItemController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.fields = [{id: 0}];
  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    $scope.fields.push({id: ($scope.fields.length)});
  }
  $scope.lineItems = [];
  $scope.getlineItems = function() {
    $http.get('<%= line_items_path(:json) %>?invoice_id=<%= params[:id] %>').then(function(lineItems) {
      console.log(lineItems);
      return $scope.lineItems;
    });
  };
 $scope.lineItems = $scope.getlineItems();
};
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="LineItemController">
<table>
  <thead><th>Quanity</th><th>Description</th><th>Price Per</th><th>Discount</th><th>Line Item Total</th></thead>
      <tr ng-repeat="lineItem in lineItems">
        <td>{{ lineItem.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ lineItem.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="field in fields">
 ....
</tr>
</table>
```

The second ng-repeat works fine.  the first one does not seem to loop through the object.  I checked the console and the array is being pulled in properly using the http get request.  If I pre populate to read $scope.lineItems = [{"name": 15, "quantity": 12 }]; it will be able to call the 15 and the 12.  So I think the break down in my code is calling the function and setting it equal to $scope.lineItems. Is there additional [] or {} that need to be included around calling the function that I am missing.  I am using rails 4 but have disabled turbolinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your function `$scope.getlineItems` does not seem to be returning anything.

Also, the $http.get method will return a promise, so you do not want to assign that directly to your `$scope.lineItems` variable. Instead, inside the `then` callback, assign your data to `$scope.lineItems`

```
$scope.getlineItems = function() {
    $http.get('<%= line_items_path(:json) %>?invoice_id=<%= params[:id] %>').then(function(lineItems) {
      console.log(lineItems);
      $scope.lineItems = lineItems;
    });
  };
 $scope.getlineItems();
```

Comment: Seems to return a blanks for {{ lineItem.name }} and {{ lineItem.quantity }} rather than the values for the array.  I can the gap where the results should be but no values.  the get request is returning an object.  Not sure I fully understand your first statement

Comment: As you have it, $scope.getlineItems does not return anything... the callback returns a value which nothing can access.

Also, you cannot just return $http.get as the result from the function is a promise object and not your actual array of data.

For testing, have the callback set $scope.lineItems with a static array.

Comment: setting $scope.lineItems = to an array seems to work. the change I added to your script was making it lineItems.data and that seemed to work!  also added a blank $scope.lineItems =[] before the function.  Thanks!